# Can my camera be saved? Or is it time to get a new one?

Tags: sony, repair, sony-nex

I am a beginner photographer and owner of the now obsolete Sony NEX 5-R mirrorless camera (bought in 2012). It has been 1) increasingly saying "cannot recognize lens" and 2) seems to have a really hard time auto-focusing, especially when I use the zoom in low lighting.

I have repeatedly wiped down the contacts, which helps temporarily with problem #1, although the "cannot recognize lens" message does continue to randomly pop up.

However, I have no idea what I should be doing for problem #2. Is this just a matter of cleaning something? Or getting it serviced? Or is my old camera finally dying its slow death?

Comment: Do you have access to another lens to try with your camera?

Comment: I have the original kit lens and a brand new telephoto zoom lens. They both act pretty wonky, so it must be an issue with the camera body.

Comment: **Update: I found a service repairman to look at the camera. His first thought was to assume that it was a problem with the lens, but since I was getting the same problem with 2 different lenses (one of which was brand new), then his next best guess was to look at the motherboard or the wiring connection to the lens contacts. Either way, it was much cheaper to fix than to buy a whole new camera, so I'm taking a chance to see if he can salvage it. It'll be a couple weeks minimum to find out, but fingers crossed he can fix it!